# Python/numpy Index Error

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have the following modified section of code, which is mimicking a section of MatLab code, which works fine;

```
import numpy as np
import math

dt = 1e-2;                      # time step
t = np.arange(0, 7, dt)         # t

mt=2
nt=2

rho=np.zeros((2,2,2,2))

Pe=np.array([[1,0],[0,0]])
Sm=np.array([[0,0],[1,0]])
Sz=np.array([[1,0],[0,- 1]])
Sy=np.array([[0,- 1j],[1j,0]])
Sx=[[0,1],[1,0]]

exp_Sz=np.zeros((2,2,len(t)))
exp_Sy=np.copy(exp_Sz)
exp_Sx=np.copy(exp_Sz)
exp_Pe=np.copy(exp_Sz)


for indx in (1,mt):
    for jndx in (1,nt):
        exp_Sz[indx,jndx,1]=np.trace(rho[:,:,indx,jndx] * Sz)
        exp_Sy[indx,jndx,1]=np.trace(rho[:,:,indx,jndx] * Sy)
        exp_Sx[indx,jndx,1]=np.trace(rho[:,:,indx,jndx] * Sx)
        exp_Pe[indx,jndx,1]=np.trace(rho[:,:,indx,jndx] * Pe)
```

But I get the following error;

```
exp_Sz[indx,jndx,1]=np.trace(rho[:,:,indx,jndx] * Sz)
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 2
```

I am unsure on what the error is.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you read this guide for MATLAB users before asking any more questions: http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Comment: Cheers for the link, will take a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for indx in (1,mt):
    for jndx in (1,nt):
         # etc
```

The nested loops above iterate over the two element *tuples* containing only the elements `1` and `mt` (outer loop) and `1` and `nt` (inner loop).

You probably wanted to iterate over `range(mt)` and `range(nt)` instead.

Note that numpy arrays are 0-index based.